# InMemoryDatabase faking the System.Data.Entity.Database property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing

In our application there used to be no tests.
Currently I'm refactoring our code so that we can write acceptance and unit tests. To do is, I need to have an abstraction of the database. We use Entity Framework 6 as our ORM.

I've created a `InMemoryDb` class which implements an interface, that also the EF-Context implements.

The EF-`DbContext` class provides a property called `Database` of type `System.Data.Entity.Database`.

Unfortunately in our code, this property is used many times for example like this:

```
Connection = (SqlConnection)dbBase.Entities.Database.Connection;
```

Where in case of the acceptance tests `Entities` is of type `InMemoryDb`.
The problem is, that in the acceptance tests, the `Database` property is **`null`** and I don't know how to set the property up correctly.

I've tried to initialize it in the constructor like this but it doesn't work:

```
public class InMemoryDb : IEfContext, IInMemoryDb
{
    public InMemoryDb()
    {
        this.per_person = new TestDbSet<per_person>();
        this.Database = new Database(null);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Database Database { get; }

    public DbSet<per_person> per_person { get; set; }

    [...]
}
```

- What is the correct way to set up this property while makeing sure that the real database isn't used?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you not using databse context ???

Comment: I am in the production code. But for my test-code (acceptance tests) I don't want to use the real database

Comment: Purpose of "Acceptence tests" to test whole application's "pipeline" - so you know that all layers integrated correctly. Your tests are closely to "integration tests". Because you created own "faked" implementation of Context - you should continue to implement all parts used by actual code. If it not possible then you should consider to change approach: re-design application by putting parts which uses `.Database` property behind another abstraction, or - better way use real or SQLLight database for running "actually" acceptence tests

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you.
Just have a look at **[Effort.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Effort.EF6/)**. That lib will setup your whole application data(baseI context in-memory with the help of NMemory.
I used it already in our applications and it works like a charm and is very easy to use.

You ware completely decoupled from external physical dependencies like SQL Server or database in SQL server.